# CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation class in OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I have console application. I am referencing the library `OfficeDevPnP.Core`. I updated to the latest package using NuGet manager. Latest assembly version is `2.28.1807`.

As soon as I updated latest package I am getting following error -

> "Error    CS0012    The type
>   'CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.20.1711.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3751622786b357c2'."

So here I am not getting the `CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation` class. I updated the previous version `2.20.1711.0` and its start working.

Is this class deprecated? What is there in latest version for the same?

Comment: nope, not deprecated. Did you refer the namespace `OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites` in the app ? Create a new console app and check if it is still there.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has not been deprecated.

It exists in the PnP Core Framework inside the `OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites` namespace.

Must be some other issue with your project or solution.

Would suggest that you create a new console application and check.

Also, ensure that all projects in your solution are updated to the latest package, it could be that one project has the latest version while other projects are not updated or are using older references.

Reference - [SiteCollectionCreationInformation.cs](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Sites/SiteCollectionCreationInformation.cs)

Comment: Thanks Gautam for the reply. Yeah I have multiple projects in my solution. I'll check in seperate console application . I'll update again.

Comment: any update on this ? If it worked, could you please accept it as answer by ticking the checkmark besides the answer , like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks :)